# How can i convert string and datetime column type in binary in rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pgcrypto

i am learning rails and working on a project in which i need to convert string column type to binary
i tried

```
change_column :workers, :sin,:binary
```

But i am not able to do so as i am getting.

```
PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "sin" cannot be cast automatically to type bytea
```

i want that my sin data should be stored in encrypted form and i am using this gem
https://github.com/stas/active_record-pgcrypto
i also want to decrypt the data while showing in the UI.
I am open for suggestions please.
Thank you

Comment: `change_column :workers, :sin, 'binary USING CAST(sin AS binary)'` - note that might not get exactly what you expect.  If you have existing data I suggest creating a new column first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest approach is to do a data migration. Create a new binary column, then for each record transform your current column to the encrypted form with `ActiveRecord::PGCrypto::SymmetricCoder.encrypt(value)` and store this encrypted value in the new binary column. Note I haven't tested it, I just checked the code of the gem.